# how to make custom wordpress rest api and get posts results with arabic language parameter

Tags: wordpress, full-text-search, arabic, wordpress-rest-api

I create API route for search
I try to get a parameter search in Arabic containing about (two words)
but it didn't work, I try almost of video, and not working
try Unicode and encode JSON also

Does anybody have a solution for it?

my API route

```
    add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route( 'wm/v1', '/search/(?p<request>.+)', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'wm_search_post',
    ) );
    enter code here
```

and the Endpoint callback function

```
function wm_search_post(WP_REST_Request $request){
    $req=JSON_encode($request['request']);
    
    return $req; 
     // here I try to test the results but get rest_no_route 
     //404 >>> but it is work if I remove parameter
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex expression is not correct and also some of your closing braces missing. Let's see the below code, it's working on my end.

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route( 'wm/v1', '/search/(?P<request>\w+)/', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'wm_search_post',
    ));
});

function wm_search_post(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    $req= $request['request'];
    return rest_ensure_response($req); 
}
```

You can get a response http://localhost/elementskit/wp-json/wm/v1/search/<pass_string_here>

Hope that will work!